# Is there any difference between using GestureDetector and Button for accesibility in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

In Flutter, we can either use GestureDetector onTap or Button to capture user press event. Is there any difference between them for accessibility like in the case of HTML (div vs button)?

Furthermore, how is GestureDetector translated into flutter web? Is it translated into a div with a onClick handler or a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Difference in accessibility

If you take a closer look at each of them, they both are triggered by the underlying callbacks.

- onPressed for the Button

> **VoidCallback onPressed**
> *Called when **the button is tapped or otherwise activated**.
> If this callback and onLongPress are null, then the button will be disabled.
> See also:
> enabled, which is true if the button is enabled.*

- onTap for GestureDetector

> **GestureTapCallback onTap**
> *A tap with a primary button has occurred.
> **This triggers when the tap gesture wins**. If the tap gesture did not win, onTapCancel is called instead.*

You will notice that there isn't much of a difference as both [GestureTapCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/GestureTapCallback.html) and [VoidCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/VoidCallback.html) are typedef equal to  `void Function();` used for the same purpose.

---

#### onTap and onPressed difference in flutter web

As for your second question, you can check [my personal website built in flutter](https://agavrel.github.io/#/) and inspect the source code yourself, I use both GestureDetector and Button, they translate to the exact same [role="button"](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role) in the html output.

---

#### Documentation:

- [GestureDetector Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)
- [TextButton Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html)
- [onPressed](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyleButton/onPressed.html)
- [onTap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector/onTap.html)

Comment: So as a conclusion => They do not differ, except for their explicit implementation (naming)?! Or did anything change since then.

Comment: No they are actually different, GestureDetector can detect a wide range of different gestures: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/interactivity/gestures#gestures my answer was pointing out that `onTap == onPressed` for Flutter Web.

Comment: The question was about accessibility. The callbacks available are a minor difference regarding accessibility vs the huge impact that comes from GestureDetector not being announced as interactive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a difference and precisely the same that comes from div vs button on the web: GestureDetector is not announced as a button, so **users will not know they can interact with it**.

For a GestureDetector to be announced you need to manually wrap it in a Semantics widget:

```
return Semantics(
      button: true,
      child: GestureDetector(
        (your props)
      ),
    );
```

The answer marked as valid is not correct, since it focuses on the callbacks and not on the accessibility itself.